# excel Format(date, "yyyymmdd") results in compile error

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure why my "Format" isn't giving me a date at the end of my filename. I have "Visual Basic For Applications" checked in references.

```
Dim dt As String

dt = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

MyFileName = Sheets("Order Summary (2)").Range("B2").Value & "_" & dt
```

I get this every time

[image]

Comment: Date is a type, you need to give it an actual date and not the data type. So: dt = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

Comment: @Sorceri - `Date` is the VBA equivalent of `=TODAY()` on the worksheet. @Matt, I can find nothing wrong with your code; it runs through just fine (to a `Debug.Print MyFileName` after the string concatenatiopn) for me.

Comment: @Sorceri `Date` is a property of `VBA.DateTime` class that should return the current date. I can enter this statement `?Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")` in the Immediate pane and get the expected result: 20170315.

Comment: This is a compile error, though, so that means the code isn't even running. Which line is highlighted when the warning is raised?

Comment: I get no issues. Try `VBA.Format()`. It sounds stupid, but I have had that work where you need to qualify VBA built-ins. It has only happened across geographic locations though, never in the US.

Comment: You probably just have another `Format` function defined somewhere in your code or in an add-in.  Fully qualifying it with `VBA.Format` is less than an ideal fix.  The ***real*** fix would be finding the identifier that is hiding the built in `Format` function and renaming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sorceri commented, use `Now`:

```
MyFileName = Sheets("Order Summary (2)").Range("B2") & VBA.Format(Now, "_yyyymmdd")
```

or if by any chance that fails, there is also `Evaluate` alternative:

```
MyFileName = ['Order Summary (2)'!B2 & TEXT(NOW(), "_yyyymmdd")]
```

Comment: I can't see how `Now` will function any different than `Date`. I use `Date` all the time for things when I don't need the time piece.

Comment: @Kyle `Date` is both a type and a method, so I am not sure if that can cause conflicts with different references, or the issue is related to the rest of the code that is not shown (more likely)

Comment: I know it is both, but I certainly hope this was contemplated in the language design. Seems like a massive  oversight if that fact causes problems.

Comment: It's sad that the accepted answer is based on the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820814/excel-formatdate-yyyymmdd-results-in-compile-error#comment72753497_42820814) that is inherently wrong. Pretending there is no issue by switching to another function that happens to do kind of the same is not a solution, it's closing your eyes and thinking no one can see you now. Please use the [correct approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820814/excel-formatdate-yyyymmdd-results-in-compile-error#comment72754520_42820814) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution was: Comintern Mar 15 '17 at 21:54

"You probably just have another Format function defined somewhere in your code or in an add-in"